# Do pointers implement iterator traits and how are they compatible with STL algorithms?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, iterator

### The Issue

---

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194977/are-all-pointers-considered-iterators) pointers are a type of an iterator and they can be used with the STL algorithms. Does that mean that they implement [iterator traits](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36530/An-Introduction-to-Iterator-Traits)?

I think not because the code

```
int a = 5, *p = &a;
std::cout << p.value_type << std::endl;
```

emits `error: request for member ‘value_type’ in ‘p’, which is of non-class type ‘int*’`, which means that `int*` isn't even a class.

### Summary

---

1. how are pointers used in STL algorithms without iterator traits?
2. If pointers can go without implementing those, can I create a custom iterator that doesn't have iterator traits? (Do STL algorithms even use those traits?)
3. When I use a pointer as an iterator, should I do something special to use it? (for example, define iterator traits...)

Comment: [The standard library provides partial specializations for pointer types `T*`, which makes it possible to use all iterator-based algorithms with raw pointers.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits#Specializations)

Comment: Use `std::iterator_traits` like `std::iterator_traits<int*>::value_type`.

Comment: @Evg Thanks! So I guess that answers 1,2. And about 3, I don't have to do anything and it will be considered that I fully support (random access) iterators, right?

Comment: @songyuanyao use them where? In the code snippet?

Comment: About 3, right. Try: `typeid(std::iterator_traits<decltype(p)>::value_type).name()`.

Comment: @Evg Whereshould I place this line and why is it needed?

Comment: Instead of `p.value_type` in your code example to show `value_type` (it's a type!).